# Java - Convert the Raw Email Content Text RFC 822 to MimeMessage

Tags: java, email, sendgrid, mime-message

Looking for an option to convert the raw email message RFC 822 to java MimeMessage object. MimeMessage has an option to convert the object to raw email context using **MimeMessage#writeTo**, self looking best approach of vice versa.

**Background:**

Sendgrid - Inbound parse invoke API and sent the raw email content part of json payload, from which we have to collect the email content and attachment files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String rawEmailString = "";
    InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawEmailString.getBytes());
    Session session = null;
    MimeMessage mimeMessageObj;
    try {

        // raw message to mime conversion - start

        mimeMessageObj = new MimeMessage(session, targetStream); 

        // raw message to mime conversion - end

        // bonus line of code to play with the message
        MimeMessageParser mimeParser = new MimeMessageParser(mimeMessageObj);
        mimeParser.parse();
        List<javax.mail.Address> to = mimeParser.getTo();
        String from = mimeParser.getFrom();
        String subject = mimeParser.getSubject();
        String bodyPlain = mimeParser.getPlainContent();
        String bodyHtml = mimeParser.getHtmlContent();
        System.out.println("From id >>>>>>>>>> " + from);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

for `org.apache.commons.mail.util.MimeMessageParser;` you can use

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: If I got the question right, it was sufficiently answered already at the first line after `try {` – but the `MimeMessageParser` stuff that follows is quite interesting nonetheless.

Comment: @tquadrat you are right, line after that are just a bonus information to extract data from the message